# Логика создания новых предикторов DataFrame используя "target" в Pandas

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с логикой процесса:

Дан df_train для обучения модели

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и df_test по которому необходимо сделать финальный прогноз.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таргет - "quantity"

Не могу понять, если я в df_train создам новый предиктор, например коэффициент потребления на 1 человека **val=quantity/pop**  как поведет себя модель при работе с df_train, ведь в df_train нет ни таргета quantity (его как раз и нужно найти) ни значений нового предиктора.

Или нужно создавать новые коэффициенты только на основании предикторов, совпадающих в df_train и df_test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Или нужно создавать новые коэффициенты только на основании
> предикторов, совпадающих в df_train и df_test.

Если вы вдруг добыли откуда-то данные для новой фичи и можете внести их и в трейн и в тест, тогда можете их использовать.
А если вычисляете из того, что имеется, то нет смысла добавлять какие-то новые фичи, зависящие от тагета, т.к. для теста вы их не сможете рассчитать и модель они только запутают - она будет думать, что эта фича прекрасно предсказывает целевую переменную и будет на неё полагаться, а в тесте этой фичи не окажется и модель останется у разбитого корыта.
Тем более, что если бы у вас были такие две прекрасные фичи, из которых простым умножением можно было бы вычислить целевую переменную, то зачем вам вообще какие-то модели были бы нужны? )
Единственное для чего добавление такого индикатора могло бы быть полезно - это для EDA (исследования данных). Но и в этом случае возможно достаточно было бы нарисовать график, по осям которого будут quantity и pop, чтобы понять что-то полезное про свои данные. Хотя скорее всего таких графиков нужно будет рисовать несколько - для разных container, например, отдельно.
А в целом, пробовать перемножать и делить фичи между собой может быть полезно, если вы хотите использовать только линейную регрессию. Ей это может помочь. А вот для "деревянных" и прочих более сложных моделей это может ничего не дать, они могут получить нужную им информацию из фич просто разбив их на диапазоны и т.д.